# Android - WebView.capturePicture fails to capture all the elements in the web page

Tags: android, android-webview, captcha, screen-capture

I am trying to extract the Captcha image from [this](https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/appointment_showDay.do?locationCode=isla&realmId=108&categoryId=205) page in android. I am using `WebView.capturePicture()` method to get the picture of the `WebView`. The problem is that the picture contains every element in the page EXCEPT the Captcha image. At first I thought may be it was a loading issue and put a `Thread.sleep()` statement in my code to wait for 2 secs after page finished loading to call the `WebView.capturePicture()` method but the result was the same. My code is:

```
WebView browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView3);

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPageFinished(view, url);


Picture picture=view.capturePicture();
PictureDrawable pd = new PictureDrawable(picture);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pd.getIntrinsicWidth(), pd.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());

}

browser.loadUrl("https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/appointment_showDay.do?locationCode=isla&realmId=108&categoryId=205");
```

**Question:** Can you please tell me why the `WebView.capturePicture()` method does not include the Captcha image in the result image?

Answer (score 1):

Use an AsyncTask and wait for 2 secounds for example. 
Captchas usually take a bit longer to load than the page because they need
to be generated.

So in your onPageFinished method start an AsyncTask which has a Thread.sleep(2000); in it's
doInBackground method.
In the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method you can draw the WebView onto your canvas.